# Sending a request with curl and a cookie loaded by the browser

Tags: php, curl

I have got this code:

```
    public function get_thead_page($cookie=null) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'');
              if($cookie) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
 }
```

Now I dont want to use my cookie value, but I want the browser to handle it for me. I wan tthe request to behave as if it was given by the browser.

So I want to the cookie to be loaded with the request instead of providing a value...

There is that value..

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'');
```

which asks for the cookie file location...but I dont want to specify the location, I want the request to be sent with a cookie being loaded somehow without specifying the path on the system..

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

The browser can't do that. CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE refers to a server-side file which the browser have no access.
You're the one who made this app. It's to you to choose the cookie's location when you create it.

Comment: hmm..I can see. I think you can do it with a java app..to control the users browsers to access the cookie or with XSS